# Данные с сервера на android

Tags: url, android, java

На сервере есть файл (php), в нем одна строчка текста, подскажите, как можно реализовать прием этого текста?

Answer (score 4):

**Вопрос звучит примерно так:** в квартире лежит кошелек, точно знаю что в малом отделении лежит купюра в 100 руб - вопрос как взять эту купюру?

**Ответ:** если у вас есть ключи от квартиры и если кошелек вам разрешено брать, то открываете ключом квартиру, заходите и в условленном месте берете кошелек открываете его и забираете купюру в 100 руб. на столе оставляете записку, взял такой то.

Это ни фига не троллинг, а конкретная инструкция как это сделать. Ровно так же надо поступать и в этом случае. Аналогом квартиры является сервер, ключи от квартиры - логин/пароль доступа к серверу, кошелек это файл, записка на столе логи сервера. Вы это телефон Android.

То есть кто-то (видимо админ сервера) должен вам дать логин/пароль от сервера (в частном случае логина/пароля может и не быть), он же админ должен положить файл или его содержимое в некую папку и показать вам этот url (условленное место).

Теперь вы, (то есть Android) должен организовать коннект к серверу (возможно с аутентификацией), взять нужный url и скачать содержимое файла (или весь файл) на телефон.

Answer (score 0):

Вот прям готовый пример - [Thread With Handlers - Android Example](http://androidexample.com/Thread_With_Handlers_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=58&aaid=83)